# com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager class not found error with appengine, JDO 3.0 and maven

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, guice, jdo

I get this error when trying to start the appengine devserver with my code:

(command is appengine-java-sdk-1.8.1.1/bin/dev_appserver.sh target/myapp/)

> INFO: An exception was caught and reported. Message:
>   org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotResolvedException: Class
>   "com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager" was not found in
>   the CLASSPATH. Please check your specification and your CLASSPATH.
>   javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Class
>   "com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager" was not found in
>   the CLASSPATH. Please check your specification and your CLASSPATH.

I'm using Guice so my module looks like this:

```
public class MyModule extends ServletModule {

@Override
public void configureServlets() {
  bind(PersistenceManagerFactory.class)
      .toInstance(JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional"));
  // ...
```

Elsewhere in my code I inject PersistenceManagerFactory and define a few simple persistence annotations and for now that's the only references to JDO I have so far.

My WEB-INF/jdoconfig.xml is pretty much an exact copy/paste from the appengine page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jdoconfig 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig">

  <persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
    <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass"
        value="org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory" />
    <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine" />
    <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true" />
    <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="true" />
    <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true" />
    <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true" />
    <property name="datanucleus.appengine.singletonPMFForName" value="true" />
  </persistence-manager-factory>
</jdoconfig>
```

DatastoreManager should be on the classpath but I suspect I may be doing something wrong with my dependencies. My maven pom file dependencies looks like this:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <com.google.inject.version>3.0</com.google.inject.version>
    <com.sun.jersey.version>1.17.1</com.sun.jersey.version>
    <org.codehaus.jackson.version>1.9.12</org.codehaus.jackson.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
      <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>14.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
      <version>${com.google.inject.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${com.google.inject.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
      <version>${com.sun.jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>${com.sun.jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-guice</artifactId>
      <version>${com.sun.jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
      <version>${org.codehaus.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>${org.codehaus.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>${org.codehaus.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
      <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
      <version>[3.2.0, 3.2.99)</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
      <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
      <version>[3.2.0, 3.2.99)</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
      <artifactId>datanucleus-jdo-query</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
      <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
      <version>0.61</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
      <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-release</version>
        <configuration>
          <api>JDO</api>
          <props>${basedir}/datanucleus.properties</props>
<!--           <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration> -->
          <verbose>true</verbose>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

I'm sure there's something obviously wrong I've missed, but as a novice to appengine and JDO, I'm lost right now.

Comment: I'm having a similar 'ClassNotFound' Exception even though the class I'm using is in the same package...

Comment: why not go back to the original Google AppEngine SDK and look at the versions of "datanucleus-" jars that it packages for you? They are not v 3.2.x. Whether that is the source of your problem is unknown, but just going off and overriding things that were set for you isn't advisable